# How to implement Jquery in Wordpress?

Tags: jquery

I am stuck on this because I'am trying to implement Jquery into Wordpress?
I tried dozen ways and none of them don't work.
So can you please help to get this the right way?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should post what you've tried.  https://css-tricks.com/snippets/wordpress/include-jquery-in-wordpress-theme/

Answer (score 0):

**5 Tips For Using jQuery with WordPress**

1. Use wp_enqueue_script() The traditional way to include jQuery in an
   HTML page is with the script tag. ...
2. Load jQuery from the Google AJAX Library. ...
3. Load jQuery in the footer. ...
4. Add jQuery as a dependency. ...
5. Proper jQuery coding conventions.

For more detail, visit url: http://www.ericmmartin.com/5-tips-for-using-jquery-with-wordpress/

Answer (score 0):

Just put this code in theme function file.

```
function include_custom_js() {
wp_register_script('custom_js', 'specify url of js file');
wp_enqueue_script('custom_js');
}
add_action( 'init','include_custom_js');
```

I hope this will work for you.

Comment: Actually `wp_register_style` should be `wp_register_script`, and `wp_enqueue_style` should be `wp_enqueue_script`. What you are doing is including `CSS`.